# Improving Query performance - T-SQL

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I have a table that is already ordered by a column 'datetime'. Because when it is inserted I store the UTC date, so it is ordered. It's a very populated table. So I am trying to improve the query performance, if it is possible.

When I use something `WHERE columnDateTime > dateToSearch` it takes too long to return the rows. As my table is already ordered by `columnDateTime` what could I do to improve this query performance. For example, when a table is ordered by a `cod` and you try to search for `cod > 40` T-SQL optimization will stop the search when it finds a cod = 41 and will return the rest of the table, cause it knows the table is ordered by that index. Is that a way that could tell T-SQL that my table is already ordered by that `columnDateTime` too?

Comment: Have you proper index  on columnDateTime  ???

Comment: A table is not really ordered.   If you could order it could not be ordered two different ways.  Check the query plans.

Comment: (1) Are you using `mysql` or `SQL Server`? `T-SQL` is Microsoft's version of SQL. (2) In relational databases the concept of "table is ordered by ..." is not accurate. The tables are not and cannot be ordered at all. However, they do have ***indexes***. And it's important to know the ***exact*** details of all your indexes when considering performance. (3) Your question is ***far too vague*** to be answerable: How long is "too long"? Saying "very populated" means ***nothing!*** (4) Exact queries ***do matter!*** Read: [ask]

Comment: When the rows are inserted there is a column that stores the UTC date when it was inserted, and it generates a cod, both columns, cod and column UTC date, is already ordered.

Comment: @RafaelAndrade Data ***IS NOT*** "ordered" in a relational database. It's only ordered by an ORDER BY clause in a query.

Comment: @CraigYoung https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described maybe read about clustered indexes before telling people incorrect information?

Comment: If it is SQL Server, there can be a logical (not physical) order via the clustered key / clustered index, although as with all performance turning - query + schema + query plan is required to provide guidance. If there is no clustered index, the table is a heap, and while you might think there is an order based on insertion, there is not an order SQL Server can rely on.

Comment: If you insert rows in strict chronological order, and the column is never updated, and it stands to reason the majority of queries would filter on it, it makes a good candidate to be the (non-unique) clustered index. But you could also just create a regular index on it, of course. Without an index, SQL Server only generates statistics about the distribution of values in the column -- these are some help, but not as much as proper indexes. It cannot exploit any order you think is there, because it can't guarantee there is one.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Maybe you should make sure you ***understand*** the concept of a clustered index correctly before you claim I'm telling people "incorrect information"? The clustered index still has the data scattered ***UNORDERED*** in various pages on the disk, and ***can*** use the clustered index to retrieve the data in a particular order. The optimiser decides whether to use the clustered index in that way ***based on*** the queries, indexes, and table statistics.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Either way, thinking about 'ordered data' in a RDBMS is suspect. Add that OP is being very obscure about what he thinks 'ordered' means; and I think you're doing him a disservice encouraging sloppy thinking.

Comment: @CraigYoung fair enough, my point was that there is ordering at a page level but that is obviously ambiguous when considering the entirety of a data table. Both of which are irrelevant if there is a complete lack of understanding any indexing and thinking a calculated field somehow defaults to being the table order

Comment: Guys, I am sorry for the newbie question. I needed to know a little bit more about clustered indexes before asking the question. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 3):

Inserting the data in order doesn't mean it is saved in order. Without getting too technical and for faster performance:

- Create a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on that column. This requiers that there are no other clustered indexes on you table and it doesn't have a `PRIMARY KEY` (or it has it `NONCLUSTERED` which is not the default). With a clustered index, the engine will do a index scan (not a full table scan) when filtering with `> datetimeValue` and doesn't need to access aditional pages for the data, since a clustered index leaves **are** the data.
- Create a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on that column. No restrictions on this clause (at least for this case), but for each match with your filtered date, the engine will need to access another page with the requested columns, unless you `INCLUDE` them when creating your index. Keep in mind that inlcuded columns will raise the size of the index and will need additional maintenance tasks like, for example, when an included column is modified.

That aside, you should check your query plan; if you have joins, function calls or additional conditions, the SQL engine **might not** use the indexes even if they exist. There are many things that could make a query run slow, you will have to post the full query execution plan (for a start) to check the details.

You can use this query to check if your table already has indexes:

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(200) = 'YourTableName'

SELECT
     SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     IndexType = CASE ind.index_id WHEN 0 THEN 'Heap' WHEN 1 THEN 'Clustered' ELSE 'Nonclustered' END,
     Disabled = ind.is_disabled,
     ColumnOrder = ic.index_column_id,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     ColumnType = y.name,
     ColumnLength = y.max_length,
     ColumnIncluded = ic.is_included_column
FROM 
    sys.indexes ind
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = col.user_type_id
WHERE 
     t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
     t.name = @table_name
ORDER BY
    SchemaName,
    t.name, 
    ind.name, 
    ic.index_column_id
```

You need to make sure that there is at least one index that has your `datetimeColumn` with `ColumnOrder = 1` and it's not disabled. If it already exists then your problem lies elsewhere and we won't be able to help much without more detail.